# Dividing a webpage using div tag

Tags: css, html

Part of project was to create a webpage/homepage. 
I was trying to divide my article section in two parts. 
Now, I searched in google to check how to divide a website in two parts/multiple parts. I know it can be done by using frame but I want to use div.

here is part of my html and css code.

```
<div id="mainArticle">
    <section class="section">
        <p>Information</p>
    </section>
    <aside class="aside">
        <p>sidebar1</p>
        <p>sidebar2</p>
    </aside>
</div>
```

CSS part of this code:

```
#mainArticle {
    clear:all;
    background-color:#ABBCDE;
    width:1000px;
    height:200px;
}
.aside {
    float:left;
    margin: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
    ;
    width:50%;
    background-color:yellow;
    height:50px;
}
.section {
    float:right;
    width: 50%;
    margin:20px 5px 20px 0px;
    background-color:cyan;
    height: 120px;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by divide?

Comment: dividing a page in main content and sidebar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your margins were throwing off the `width: 50%` by adding additional spacing. Try removing the margins.

Is this the desired result?

```
#mainArticle {
    clear:all;
    background-color:#ABBCDE;
    width:1000px;
    height:200px;
}
.aside {
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    background-color:yellow;
    height:50px;
}
.section {
    float:right;
    width: 50%;
    background-color:cyan;
    height: 120px;
}
```